# Connect wireless mouse and keyboard set to different computers

Tags: wireless-networking, keyboard, mouse, connection, dongle

So I found this mouse I really liked, but it came with a set. The set was very expensive but it would be a good price when someone else got the keyboard and we shared the price.
But only 1 receiver came with the set, and we want to connect the mouse to my laptop, and the keyboard to a desktop pc, is there any way to reprogram the mouse or keyboard so it connects separately? I'm also willing to buy a new receiver, but I haven't figured out yet whether that works.
Thanks!

Comment: What's the brand and model of the set? Do you have to pair keyboard and mouse separately when connecting them?

Comment: https://www.trust.com/en/product/21383-evo-silent-wireless-keyboard-with-mouse This is the set, I don't know if I have to pair them separately, I didn't open the box yet in case I wanted to return the set. (The mouse does have a connect button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The USB key is probably Bluetooth, so if one machine already has bluetooth built-in, then it **might** find one of the devices; but if you install any proprietary driver/software, that would likely override it.

A parallel situation I encountered recently is that 2 Logitech devices, requiring slightly different dongles, will not both connect to one machine because each needs its specific software/drivers, each of which locks out the other device.

Unless you can return the package after opening - in the EU you can do that for up to 14 days without explanation [Look up 'distance selling regulations' for your country's version of the law] - then you'd have to accept the risk.

Comment: So you're saying its very likely to not work?

Comment: I think you've got a 50/50 shot, assuming you have one machine that already has bluetooth. If you don't have that, then it's not even vaguely likely to work.